# Crystal Reports find the first 3 words of a string

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a database field with strings like this

```
oh the sea OToole was right
I like ramen but
Rowing like a Blue but not an artist
```

They are actual words separated with space

I want to find to extract the first 3 words

The result would be like below

```
oh the sea 
I like ramen 
Rowing like a
```

I tried the following

```
 ExtractString({tbname.field1},""," ") & " " & ExtractString({tbname.field1}," "," ") & ExtractString({tbname.field1},"   "," ")
```

It did work for the the first two fields but not the second

I tried the one below too

```
split({tbname.field1}, " ")[1] & " " & split({tbname.field1}, " ")[2] 
& " " & split({tbname.field1}, " ")[3]
```

It gives me an error saying the indice must be between 1 and the size of the array

Any insights are more than welcome

Comment: I was thinking of creating a sql command to do that...but it seems even worse as I will need to create functions and etc ... -_-

Comment: I there are only two fields hence you are getting error

Comment: Hi @Siva, which 2 fields you are talking about?

Comment: You are splitting and retriving the data but you are getting error..that error appears when you sre trying to retrive more items than the items present in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ubound(Split({tbname.field1})) < 3 then
Join(Split({tbname.field1})[1 to ubound(Split({tbname.field1}))]," ")
else Join(Split({tbname.field1})[1 to 3]," ")
```

Comment: This condition worked for me actually `ubound(Split({tbname.field1})) < 3 OR ubound(Split({tbname.field1})) > 0` I tried to edit your answer but 'powers' in charge did not see it as appropriate :)

Comment: i saw the recommendation but it wouldn't let me approve it. I guess I don't have enough reputation!

Comment: But you can change your answer :) (if you want to , of course)

Answer (score 1):

** edited to reflect data is contained in a single row, rather than 3 separate rows

Try:

```
// defined delimiter
Local Stringvar CRLF := Chr(10)+Chr(13);

// split CRLF-delimited string into an array
Local Stringvar Array rows := Split({Command.WORDS}, CRLF);

// the results of all the work
Local Stringvar Array results;

// process each 'row'
Local Numbervar i;
for i := 1 to ubound(rows) do (
  // increment the array, then add first 3 words
  Redim Preserve results[Ubound(results)+1];
  results[ubound(results)]:=Join(Split(rows[i])[1 to 3]," ")
);

// create CRLF-delimited string
Join(results, CRLF);
```